# CouchDB FB Authentication Sign Up

Tags: facebook, couchdb

I am trying to enable FB Authentication in a CouchDB app. I am using IrisCouch which says it has this built in, but having numerous problems. Tried a bunch of tutorials listed here:

http://www.iriscouch.com/blog/2011/07/coffeescript-facebook-and-futon#facebook_authentication
https://getsatisfaction.com/iriscouch/topics/ocasta_labs_facebook_authentication

But they dont seem to be working. I go to my configuration in Futon and set the client id and secret, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Thoughts?

--Ashley

EDIT:
Okay so I got the authentication through FB working, now just working on the signup, I am getting the error "creating a user doc requires sha1.js to be loaded in the page"

However when I read through my couch.js file I see hashing already exists there, am I missing a js file somewhere?